# Opening android app from a link, Intent is missing the link information

Tags: android, deep-linking

I've mapped my Android app to a domain by following this page. https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html

If my app is not running, it works great. When I switch from the running app to an email with the link embedded in it. Clicking the link has the app just resume where it left off. So the Intent doesn't actually have the URL that reopened the app.

Anyone have any thoughts?